# Event Start and End Date-time is shown incorrectly when record is created via Site Guest User

Tags: apex, event, webhooks

I have exposed Apex class as webhook which is called by an external service. When this webhook is called I am using the posted data to create Event records.

However when I open the created event record the displayed start and end date time are completely different from what was saved.

When I perform a SOQL query on the event record I get the correct start and end date-time which means that it was saved properly. The issue only happens when I view the event record.

I have set the timezone for my Guest Site User to EST New York.

This is the screenshot of the SOQL query result

[image]

This is how the event record actually looks when I open it

[image]

I cannot figure out for the life of me what is going on and why it is showing a different date time.

Comment: Initial thought is what is your timezone set to...but you've probably checked that?

Comment: It looks correct to me. Times are saved in GMT in the database, and converted when displayed in the UI.

Comment: @Girbot yes I have changed the timezone to EST for relevant users

Comment: @sfdcfox so when I am getting the dates from the webhook I am getting it in GMT? So I need to explicitly save it in the timezone I want to?

Comment: @codeinprogress Ideally, convert the time to GMT and send that to the database instead of the time they select, but otherwise, specifying the offset in the payload should also work.